# Placing and styling EdgeLabels in Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I have:

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 3},
 VertexStyle -> Orange,
 VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 16],
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 EdgeStyle -> Black,
 EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> Placed["0.9", 0.5]}]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

I'd like to center the 0.9 on the arrow below the vertex labeled 1 with a white background. How can I do this? And I'd like to increase its font size.

Answer (score 3):

**Version 9.0:**

```
g =  Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 3}, 
  VertexStyle -> Orange, VertexSize -> 0.3, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Italic, 16], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], EdgeStyle -> Black, 
  EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 1) -> Placed[Framed[Style["0.9", 14, Italic, Bold, Blue], 
     Background -> White, FrameStyle -> White], "Middle"]}]
```

[image]

**Version 11:**

If you don't mind having a `Graphics` object (instead of a `Graph` object), you can post-process `Show[g]` to adjust the label position:

```
Show[g] /. ImageScaled[{_, _}] :> ImageScaled[{.5, -.7}]
```

[image]

If you do need to have a `Graph` object, you can extract the edge shape  and edge label from `ToBoxes[g]`, make the necessary adjustments and use the resulting expression as the value of `EdgeShapeFunction` for the edge `1->1`:

```
edgeshape = Cases[ToBoxes[g], {ab : _ArrowBox, ib: _InsetBox} :> 
  {ab, ib /. ImageScaled[{_, _}] :> ImageScaled[{.5, -.7}]}, {0, ∞}][[1]];

Row[{g, SetProperty[{g, 1->1}, {EdgeLabels -> None, EdgeShapeFunction -> (edgeshape &)}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in Mathematica 11. Any ideas why?